# i am using "Insert all" with no_append hints

Tags: oracle11g

I am using "insert all" to insert the data in multiple table. Do i need to provide append hint or "insert all" statement by default inserted data in append (direct_path) mode ?

If it is in Append (direct_path) mode then my table will fragmented after the certain period of time as i am performing delete and update on this table. Anyone can let me know, how can i cure form fragmentation?

Comment: If it is in Append (direct_path) mode then my table will fragmented after the certain period of time as i am performing delete and update on this table. 
Anyone can let me know, how can i cure form fragmentation?

Comment: `insert all` statement doesn't perform direct path insert by default.

Comment: If you don't want fragmentation, don't use direct-path inserts. Why do you want to use direct-path here? The 'cure' for fragmentation is to rebuild the table, e.g. `alter table <your-table> move`, but it has side-effects, and it's better to avoid the situation if you can.

Comment: It's all rather abstract. Perhaps show some example code?